# I can't find PIL in python

Tags: python

I have installed Pillow and can see where it is installed but from PIL import Image doesn't work.  Says no module called PIL.  Have tried the 'import image' instead as well and still not result?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Something")
root.geometry('600x600')

def resize_image(event):
    new_width = event.width
    new_height = event.height
    image = copy_of_image.resize((new_width, new_height))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage('fun.gif')
    label.config(image = photo)
    label.image = photo #avoid garbage collection

image = Image.open('fun.gif')
copy_of_image = image.copy()
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
label = ttk.Label(root, image = photo)
label.bind('<Configure>', resize_image)
label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand = YES)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `import Image` (capital `I`)

Comment: Sorry, I actually used import Image - just lazy typist

Comment: more concerned about the fact that it shows me where I have imported Pillow but then says 'No module named PIL'

Comment: Some actual code and actual tracebacks please, or nobody is going to be able to help.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\me\My Documents\Python 3.5\tKinter\SportsdayGif2.py", line 3, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: could you please inform us of **how** you installed Pillow and assuming it was with pip what `--version` of pip it was as well as what version of python you are using (they may be different)

Comment: py -3.5 -m pip install pillow

Comment: the pip version was 8.1.1

Answer (score -1):

I think if your installation is right then it will create a PIL directory in your Pyhton3x/Lib/site_packges/PIL.If it is not there then try to clean Pillow from site_packages and install it again.